# Andriod gradle dependency:library have an error

Tags: android

I'm trying to add below dependency to my app level gradle file

```
player-service-cast-framework:16.2.0
```

but got error while building.

Below is my list of dependencies in app level gradle.

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.8.4'
implementation 'com.github.HaarigerHarald:android-youtubeExtractor:v1.7.0'
implementation "com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:28.0.0"
implementation  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:16.2.0'

implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0"
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0"
annotationProcessor "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0"
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

and the error is showing at this line.
     `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`

Comment: Post your logcat here.

Comment: You need to add your Error phrase too. I'm not sure what could happen.

Comment: @Kabir I don't think his error has anything to do with the logcat. It's just about dependencies.

Comment: Please show your top level `build.gradle` file, thanks. Btw, posting the error your get might be beneficial.

Comment: Did something help you or not? If any answer was helpful please select it. If not tell me so I can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using the old `android.support` library. What you should be using is the `AndroidX` library. So, replace your:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

with this:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
```

But that is not your only error. As you are using a lot of `android.support` dependencies, I assume you are using an old project, so see this: [Migrate to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate). All of your old dependencies have a new implementation now.